# Creating separate projects for entity classes ( POCO classes) and DBContext classes

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I have generated my Database layer (Database First Entity Model) by using entity framework 6.1. Now all the classes generated are in the same project as well as in the same namespace i.e. Example.DataAccessLayer. For separation of concerns, I have moved my entity classes(POCO classes) that are under Model.tt file to separate project and under namespace Example.DataModel. The reason I have done this is because then I can use Example.DataModel project in my websites so that the DbContext classes are not visible and all the data management is done through my business layer i.e. Example.BusinessLayer.

Now doing this I have to give reference of my Example.DataModel project to Example.DataAccessLayer. As it is suggested in some of the tutorial, after doing this one has to change the  Custom Tool Namespace of MyModel.Context.tt file to Example.DataModel so the entity classes are visible. But by doing this  the DBContext and DataModel comes under same namespace that is Example.DataModel.

Now the question is, is there a way to generate my entity model with my context and entities classes in separate projects and in separate namespace without giving my DBcontext.tt file custom tool namespace ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Code-First to connect to you existing DB? Then you have full control of where Models and DbContext lives.